# FFMpeg encoding RGB images to H264

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264, rtp, libavcodec

I'm developing a DirectShow filter which has 2 input pins (1 for audio, 1 for video). I'm using libavcodec/libavformat/libavutil of FFMpeg for encoding the video to H264, audio to AAC and mux it/stream using RTP. So far I was able to encode video and audio correctly using libavcodec but now I see that FFMpeg seems to support RTP muxing too. Unfortunatelly, I can't find any example code which shows how to perform H264 encoding and RTP muxing. Does anybody know good samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking out the code in [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr).  Specifically, this file [muxmp4.c](https://trac.handbrake.fr/browser/branches/0.7.3/libhb/muxmp4.c), which was a jem I found working with FFMpeg / RTP.  Be sure and use **av_interleaved_write_frame()** and the **extradata** fields correctly.  Those were some key differences I remember for RTP.

Still, I had some stability issues with RTP/RTSP with FFMpeg, (I'm sure it's getting better).  I had much better luck with [live555](http://www.live555.com/), and you can look at the code in [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) and [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) for good examples on how to use it.