# ffmpeg: how to save h264 raw data as mp4 file

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264, mp4

I encode h264 data by libavcodec.
ex.

```
while (1) {
  ...
  avcodec_encode_video(pEnc->pCtx, OutBuf, ENC_OUTSIZE, pEnc->pYUVFrame);
  ...
}
```

If I directly save OutBuf data as a .264 file, it can`t be play by player. Now I want to save OutBuf

as a mp4 file. Anyone know how to do this by ffmpeg lib? thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You use `avformat_write_header`, `av_interleaved_write_frame`, `avformat_write_trailer` and friends.

Their usage is shown in the [muxing example](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/muxing.c) of FFmpeg.

See a similar topic: [Raw H264 frames in mpegts container using libavcodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964142/raw-h264-frames-in-mpegts-container-using-libavcodec) with also writing to a file (different container, same API)

See also links from answer here: [FFMpeg encoding RGB images to H264](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911798/ffmpeg-encoding-rgb-images-to-h264/5995994#5995994)